SET SSL_VERIFY as NO to download CSV file from KDB
I have kdb 64 bit installed on windows and wanted to run below kdb command to download a csv file and load it as table into data variable.
q)("**III";1#",") 0: "\n" vs .Q.hg"https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/f9bf-2cp4/rows.csv"

But this leads to a 'conn ( connection error ) .
C80A0000:error:80000003:system library:file_ctrl:No such process:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:297:calling fopen(C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSL\SSL/server-crt.pem, rb)
C80A0000:error:10080002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:300:
C80A0000:error:0A080002:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl\ssl_rsa.c:448:
C80A0000:error:80000003:system library:BIO_new_file:No such process:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSL\SSL/cacert.pem, r)
C80A0000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
C80A0000:error:05880002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file_ex:system lib:crypto\x509\by_file.c:228:
'conn. OS reports: An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call.
  [0]  ("**III";1#",") 0: "\n" vs .Q.hg"https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/f9bf-2cp4/rows.csv"

On unix we can export variable as
$ export SSL_VERIFY=NO

But how do we do equivalent of this in windows ? I tried to modify environment variable in windows. But this does not seem to work.


try with http not https
q)("**III";1#",") 0: "\n" vs .Q.hg "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/f9bf-2cp4/rows.csv"
140604299227904:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:288:fopen('/usr/lib/ssl/server-crt.pem','r')
140604299227904:error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:290:
140604299227904:error:140DC002:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:../ssl/ssl_rsa.c:615:
140604299227904:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/usr/lib/ssl/cacert.pem','r')
140604299227904:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
140604299227904:error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib:../crypto/x509/by_file.c:199:
'conn. OS reports: Protocol not available
  [0]  ("**III";1#",") 0: "\n" vs .Q.hg "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/f9bf-2cp4/rows.csv"
                                  ^
q))("**III";1#",") 0: "\n" vs .Q.hg "http://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/f9bf-2cp4/rows.csv"
DBN      SCHOOL NAME                                                      Num of SAT Test Takers SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score SAT Math Avg. Score
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"01M292" "HENRY STREET SCHOOL FOR INTERNATIONAL STUDIES"                  29                     355                             404                
"01M448" "UNIVERSITY NEIGHBORHOOD HIGH SCHOOL"                            91                     383                             423                
"01M450" "EAST SIDE COMMUNITY SCHOOL"                                     70                     377                             402                
"01M458" "FORSYTH SATELLITE ACADEMY"                                      7                      414                             401                
"01M509" "MARTA VALLE HIGH SCHOOL"                                        44                     390                             433                
"01M515" "LOWER EAST SIDE PREPARATORY HIGH SCHOOL"                        112                    332                             557                
"01M539" "NEW EXPLORATIONS INTO SCIENCE, TECHNOLOGY AND MATH HIGH SCHOOL" 159                    522                             574                
"01M650" "CASCADES HIGH SCHOOL"                                           18                     417                             418                
"01M696" "BARD HIGH SCHOOL EARLY COLLEGE"                                 130                    
....


accepting this as an answer as this resolves the issue, but ideally would have liked a way to see how SSL can be set to NO.

@Invictus, ack, if i find out i'll post.
